# How to disable ListView touch events? Allow only childview clicks

Tags: android, listview, event-handling

I need to disable touchevent handling for a listview but allow it's children to receive clicks. I have a frame layout which has a mapview and the listview over it. When the list is empty, I want the map to handle all touch events but when the list is filled, I want the list items to receive clickevents.

Answer (score 2):

You could intercept all touch events in a custom FrameLayout (your root ViewGroup) using onInterceptTouchEvent(): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent).

What you do there is capture the MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN event and decide whether the event is meant for the ListView or the MapView depending on whether the ListView is empty (touches go to the MapView) or filled and within the borders of the ListView (touches go to the ListView).
In both cases return true and capture the following ACTION_DOWN event in onTouchEvent() (still FrameLayout). That way all touch events up to ACTION_CANCEL will go to your FrameLayout's onTouchEvent().

Your FrameLayout's onTouchEvent() will dispatch all touch events either to the ListView or the MapView. The decision which views gets the events has been taken in onInterceptTouchEvent(), so you need to store the result of that decision somehow. That decision is valid between the ACTION_DOWN and the ACTION_POINTER_UP, ACTION_UP, ACTION_CANCEL events.

I'm not sure whether you want to disable all touch events for the non empty ListView that don't select a list item (flinging, scrolling etc.)? Because that would complicate matters considerably. Although I don't think that makes sense from a user perspective as list items not fitting the ListView's viewport could not be clicked because you can't scroll up or down.

Don't expect this to work easily. Understanding the flow of motion events and the interaction between onInterceptTouchEvent() and onTouchEvent() is challenging and making it work even more so. But I'm confident that this is a feasible way to solve your problem.